# jquery custom scrollbars in slider example

Tags: jquery, scrollbar, jquery-slider

I'm trying out a sample `jquery` from here: http://jqueryui.com/slider/#side-scroll
I copied the source code at "view source" and when I run it, it looks pretty much the same, but it is showing the native scrollbar instead of the custom scrollbar showing on the site.

Can anyone help me how to get those custom scrollbars?

I included the source code for convenience:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>jQuery UI Slider - Slider scrollbar</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
  <style>
  .scroll-pane { overflow: auto; width: 99%; float:left; }
  .scroll-content { width: 2440px; float: left; }
  .scroll-content-item { width: 100px; height: 100px; float: left; margin: 10px; font-size: 3em; line-height: 96px; text-align: center; }
  .scroll-bar-wrap { clear: left; padding: 0 4px 0 2px; margin: 0 -1px -1px -1px; }
  .scroll-bar-wrap .ui-slider { background: none; border:0; height: 2em; margin: 0 auto;  }
  .scroll-bar-wrap .ui-handle-helper-parent { position: relative; width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0 auto; }
  .scroll-bar-wrap .ui-slider-handle { top:.2em; height: 1.5em; }
  .scroll-bar-wrap .ui-slider-handle .ui-icon { margin: -8px auto 0; position: relative; top: 50%; }
  </style>
  <script>
  $(function() {
    //scrollpane parts
    var scrollPane = $( ".scroll-pane" ),
      scrollContent = $( ".scroll-content" );

    //build slider
    var scrollbar = $( ".scroll-bar" ).slider({
      slide: function( event, ui ) {
        if ( scrollContent.width() > scrollPane.width() ) {
          scrollContent.css( "margin-left", Math.round(
            ui.value / 100 * ( scrollPane.width() - scrollContent.width() )
          ) + "px" );
        } else {
          scrollContent.css( "margin-left", 0 );
        }
      }
    });

    //append icon to handle
    var handleHelper = scrollbar.find( ".ui-slider-handle" )
    .mousedown(function() {
      scrollbar.width( handleHelper.width() );
    })
    .mouseup(function() {
      scrollbar.width( "100%" );
    })
    .append( "<span class='ui-icon ui-icon-grip-dotted-vertical'></span>" )
    .wrap( "<div class='ui-handle-helper-parent'></div>" ).parent();

    //change overflow to hidden now that slider handles the scrolling
    scrollPane.css( "overflow", "hidden" );

    //size scrollbar and handle proportionally to scroll distance
    function sizeScrollbar() {
      var remainder = scrollContent.width() - scrollPane.width();
      var proportion = remainder / scrollContent.width();
      var handleSize = scrollPane.width() - ( proportion * scrollPane.width() );
      scrollbar.find( ".ui-slider-handle" ).css({
        width: handleSize,
        "margin-left": -handleSize / 2
      });
      handleHelper.width( "" ).width( scrollbar.width() - handleSize );
    }

    //reset slider value based on scroll content position
    function resetValue() {
      var remainder = scrollPane.width() - scrollContent.width();
      var leftVal = scrollContent.css( "margin-left" ) === "auto" ? 0 :
        parseInt( scrollContent.css( "margin-left" ) );
      var percentage = Math.round( leftVal / remainder * 100 );
      scrollbar.slider( "value", percentage );
    }

    //if the slider is 100% and window gets larger, reveal content
    function reflowContent() {
        var showing = scrollContent.width() + parseInt( scrollContent.css( "margin-left" ), 10 );
        var gap = scrollPane.width() - showing;
        if ( gap > 0 ) {
          scrollContent.css( "margin-left", parseInt( scrollContent.css( "margin-left" ), 10 ) + gap );
        }
    }

    //change handle position on window resize
    $( window ).resize(function() {
      resetValue();
      sizeScrollbar();
      reflowContent();
    });
    //init scrollbar size
    setTimeout( sizeScrollbar, 10 );//safari wants a timeout
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="scroll-pane ui-widget ui-widget-header ui-corner-all">
  <div class="scroll-content">
    <div class="scroll-content-item ui-widget-header">1</div>
    <div class="scroll-content-item ui-widget-header">2</div>
    <div class="scroll-content-item ui-widget-header">3</div>
    <div class="scroll-content-item ui-widget-header">4</div>
    <div class="scroll-content-item ui-widget-header">5</div>
    <div class="scroll-content-item ui-widget-header">6</div>
    <div class="scroll-content-item ui-widget-header">7</div>
    <div class="scroll-content-item ui-widget-header">8</div>
    <div class="scroll-content-item ui-widget-header">9</div>
    <div class="scroll-content-item ui-widget-header">10</div>
    <div class="scroll-content-item ui-widget-header">11</div>
    <div class="scroll-content-item ui-widget-header">12</div>
    <div class="scroll-content-item ui-widget-header">13</div>
    <div class="scroll-content-item ui-widget-header">14</div>
    <div class="scroll-content-item ui-widget-header">15</div>
    <div class="scroll-content-item ui-widget-header">16</div>
    <div class="scroll-content-item ui-widget-header">17</div>
    <div class="scroll-content-item ui-widget-header">18</div>
    <div class="scroll-content-item ui-widget-header">19</div>
    <div class="scroll-content-item ui-widget-header">20</div>
  </div>
  <div class="scroll-bar-wrap ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom">
    <div class="scroll-bar"></div>
  </div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found another very lightweight plugin that covers a scrollbar:http://baijs.nl/tinyscrollbar/